# AWS Cloudformation: cli creds file created but not found during later configsets

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, aws-cloudformation

I have an AWS Cloudformation template that, among other things, creates a public EC2 instance with some `Metadata` in the form of `AWS::Cloudformation::Init` configsets. When run, these configsets are meant to 1) install `chef-solo`, 2)create an AWS `credentials` file in `/home/ec2-user/.aws/credentials`, 3) use the credentials in `2)` with the aws cli to retrieve a Chef cookbook from AWS S3, 4) run the cookbook.

Everything is working fine until `3)`. This breaks and, according to the `cfn-init` logs, the problem is that the credentials for the aws cli can't be found. However, step `2)` completes successfully and when I log into the server manually I can see the `credentials` file in the right place and successfully run `aws s3` commands from the prompt (the same ones that were supposed to be run automatically as part of the template.

Here is the error from the logs:

```
2016-05-04 04:03:14,950 P2482 [INFO] Command 2_fetch-cookbook
2016-05-04 04:03:15,977 P2482 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2016-05-04 04:03:15,977 P2482 [INFO]    Unable to locate credentials
2016-05-04 04:03:15,977 P2482 [INFO]    Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining
```

...and here is what it looks like when I log in:

```
ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-243 ~]$ ls .aws
credentials
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-243 ~]$ aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket
2016-05-04 00:27:43      41472 kitchen.tar.gz
```

I've been fiddling with this for quite a while and just can't seem to get it, so I'm hoping someone here might be able to help. =) Below you can find the relevant code for the EC2 instance. Note that I have to use `sudo su` before installing `chef-solo` since that script downloads and unpacks an `rpm`. Then I switch back to the `ec2-user` for everything else.

```
"EC2Instance" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Description" : "EC2 Instance",
  "Metadata" : {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "configSets" : {
        "Setup" : [ "InstallChef", "SetAWSCreds", "Cook" ]
      },

      "InstallChef" : {
        "commands" : {
          "1_sudo" : {
            "command" : "sudo su"
          },
          "2_install-chef" : {
            "cw": "/home/ec2-user",
            "command" : "curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash"
          },
          "3_su" : {
            "command" : "su ec2-user"
          }
        }
      },

      "SetAWSCreds" : {
        "files" : {
          "/home/ec2-user/.aws/credentials" : {
            "content" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
              "[default]\n",
              "aws_access_key_id = ",
              { "Ref" : "AwsAccessKeyId" },
              "\n",
              "aws_secret_access_key = ",
              { "Ref" : "AwsSecretAccessKey" },
              "\n"
            ]]},
            "owner" : "ec2-user",
            "group" : "ec2-user"
          }
        }
      },

      "Cook" : {
        "commands" : {
          "1_ensure_ec2-user" : {
            "command" : "su ec2-user"
          },
          "2_fetch-cookbook" : {
            "cw" : "/home/ec2-user",
            "command" : "aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/kitchen.tar.gz ."
          },
          "3_unzip-cookbook" : {
            "cw" : "/home/ec2-user",
            "command" : "tar xvf kitchen.tar.gz"
          },
          "4_cook" : {
            "cw" : "/home/ec2-user/kitchen",
            "command" : "sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j web.json"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Properties" : {
    "ImageId" : "ami-08111162",
    "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyPairName" },
    "InstanceType" : "t2.micro",
    "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet" },
    "SecurityGroupIds" : [ { "Ref" : "SecurityGroup" } ],
    "UserData" : {
      "Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",

          "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
          "                      -r EC2Instance",
          "                      -c Setup"
        ]]
      }
    }
  }
```